# Is the following claim correct in general?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Modified Fitting Lemma:

> **Claim :** If $G$ is a finite group and $f$ is an endomorphism of $G$, then for some $n \ge 1$,  $G = \operatorname{ Ker } (f^{n}) \times \operatorname{ Im } (f^{n})$

Where $\text{ Ker } f^n$ means the kernel of $f^{n}$.

One Example which I have tried is identity map assume $n=1$ kernel will be trivial so $G = \operatorname { Ker } f \times \operatorname{ Im } f$.

Is the claim is true can anyone explain how? If not give an counter example.

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you mean for some $n \ge 1$ or for all $n  \ge 1$? But in any case, try  $G=S_3$ with $|{\rm Im} f|=2$. (BTW, I have no idea what you mean by dropping the condition that $f$ needs to be normal.)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thanks - although the comment was more intended as a criticism of the post rather than as a request for enlightenment.

Comment: @ Derek Holt This is a standard statement from book. It is from the book title  Group theory by Hungerford 1973.

Comment: I just searched for it, and in the version I found it says "for some $n \ge 1$" not "for $n \ge 1$".

Comment: Although I have already added the meaning of $n \ge 1$ in the question

Answer (score 4):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$I have a version of Fitting's Lemma for non-commutative groups (which is contained in the proof of Theorem 4.1 of [this 1985 paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869385900687/pdf?md5=55342031ff0ba61be8c00dec9954d878&pid=1-s2.0-0021869385900687-main.pdf), see also Theorem 4.2 of [this 2013 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.2554.pdf)), but you all you get in general is a semidirect product, the image of $f^{n}$ being not necessarily normal, as shown by Derek Holt's $S_{3}$ example.

The version from [the 2013 paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869385900687/pdf?md5=55342031ff0ba61be8c00dec9954d878&pid=1-s2.0-0021869385900687-main.pdf) sounds

> Let $G$ be a group  which satisfies the ascending chain condition on
>     normal subgroups, and the descending chain condition on subgroups. (Of course a finite group satisfies both.)
>
> Let $\phi$ be an endomorphism of $G$.   Then there is
>     a natural 
>     number $n$ such that $\ker(\phi^{n}) = \ker(\phi^{n+i})$ and $G^{\phi^{n}}
>   = G^{\phi^{n+i}}$ for each $i \ge 0$.
>     We have:
>
> 1. $G$ is the semidirect product of the normal subgroup $K = \ker(\phi^{n})$ by the subgroup $H = G^{\phi^{n}}$,
> 2. the restriction of  $\phi$ to $K$
>          is nilpotent, and
> 3. the restriction of  $\phi$ to  $H$  is an
>          automorphism.